# How can I get text after text in xPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My XML-Documents contains a text that says:

```
identifier=something;
```

I need to store "something" in

```
<xsl:variable name="id" select="???">
```

However I do not know in which node I can find

```
identifier=something;
```

and I can not access the XML-Document to check it, since the document is created in a dynamic Process.

My question now is, how I can access "something" using XPath?

Comment: can you post your input xml (at least the portion where identifier=something is )?

Comment: Have you tried `//[contains(text(),'identifier')` ?

Comment: sadly no, since I can not access the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that data is in a single text node you get that with `//text()[contains(., 'identifier=')]` and `substring-after(//text()[contains(., 'identifier=')], 'identifier=')` gives you the `something;` and then a further `substring-before(substring-after(//text()[contains(., 'identifier=')], 'identifier='), ';')` shouldl give you `something`.